# Why are fractions with a negative denominator valid?

Tags: fractions

Whenever in a fraction, there is $0$ in the denominator, the fraction becomes $\infty$ or indeterminate. But why do we consider those fractions valid that have some negative numbers in the denominator since those numbers are even smaller than $0$ ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by _smaller_.  If you mean "smaller in magnitude," then negative numbers are not smaller than zero.

Comment: As below, denominators are *normalized* to be positive simply as a matter of *convenience* 

$$\rm  x = \dfrac{a}{-b} \iff (-b)\,x  =a \iff b\, x = -a \iff x = \dfrac{-a}{b} = -\dfrac{a}b$$  More generally, one often normalizes the leading coefficient of a polynomial to be positive (or, further, to be $1$ if the coefficient ring is a field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, $\frac{p}{0}$ never becomes $\infty$, it is simply undefined.

Now, a fraction $\frac{p}{q}$, with $p,q$ integers and $q\ne 0$, is introduced in order to solve a problem. The problem is to solve the equation $q\cdot x = p$. This solution, even though described with integers alone, does not always have a solution in the integers. So, we extend the integers by introducing solutions to all such equations *as long as it makes sense*. An example where it does not make sense is the equation $0\cdot x = p$, where $p\ne 0$, since we wish to retain the fact that $0\cdot x=0$. There are some subtleties here, solutions to different equation may lead to essentially that same fraction. This is solved by the familiar equations of the form $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$ and so on.

Now, fractions with negative denominators simply are solutions for equations of the form $-7\cdot x = 2$ or $-5x=17$. There is no reason to exclude such solutions. In fact, by adjoining all solutions to all equations of the form $qx=p$, where $p,q$ are integers and $q\ne 0$ (and properly identifying fractions that only appear to be different in form) one obtains the *field* of the rational numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Fractions, like all the rest of mathematics, consist of certain symbols written on a page. As the creators of these symbols, we can decide how to manipulate them however we want, and what meaning to give them. The usual meaning we have decided to give to
$$\frac{a}{b}$$
is "*this symbol, when multiplied by $b$, produces $a$*".  Thus, for example, $\frac{1}{2}$ is a symbol satisfying
$$\frac{1}{2}\times 2=1.$$
Now, the reason why fractions whose denominator is $0$ are usually taken to be "undefined" is that (unless we are very careful / in a more advanced setting) no matter how hard we try, there is no way of making the symbol
$$\frac{a}{0}$$
satisfy all of the rules we want it to; for example, since we want multiplication to be associative, we should have
$$\frac{1}{0}\times \mathopen{\bigg(}0\times 2\mathclose{\bigg)}=\left(\frac{1}{0}\times 0\right)\times 2$$
But the left side produces
$$\frac{1}{0}\times \mathopen{\bigg(}0\times 2\mathclose{\bigg)}=\frac{1}{0}\times 0=1,$$
while the right side produces
$$\left(\frac{1}{0}\times 0\right)\times 2=1\times 2=2.$$
Thus, we give up on defining division by $0$.

But this problem does not exist for fractions with negative denominators; everything works just fine. There's no reason to consider them invalid. In fact, once we start considering complex numbers like $2+3i$, we often like to divide by them too!